# Check that the .NET 3.5 framework is installed

Tags: c#, .net

I need to perform a function in C # to verify that the .NET 3.5 framework is installed on the client's machine.
How can I do this without using Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey ( "Software \ Windows \ Microsoft.NET \ ..."), since this function has to be used on several different machines all with different ways to framework?

Thank you

Comment: How do you install your application ?

Comment: There is a chicken and egg issue. Why do you want to use C# to test the installation of .NET Framework? On a machine with no .NET Framework installed, C# programs won't run at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If .NET is installed on a machine it will have the registry keys as well. Microsoft states this as the method for detected the client's version of the .NET framework.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh925568(v=vs.110).aspx

There is also a version object in the Environment class that has information about the major, minor, build versions of the framework that is running. (Which Microsoft recommends that you do not use it 4.5 and later and instead use the registry check).

Make sure you check the correct values though since .NET 3.5 and .Net 3.0's CLR version is still 2.0.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb822049.aspx

Comment: but what if I do not know which is the directory where the framwork is installed

Comment: Even though the Registry has a similar layout to the file directory it is not the same as the file directory. The registry is a database of settings that programs use to check information, load user settings, etc. Microsoft guarantees that if .NET is installed it will create registry keys in this location in the registry.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to this msdn article on this subject. That registry location will be the same on any machine with the framework installed, it is not a path to where the framework is installed so it is valid to use.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh925568(v=vs.110).aspx